# count records on three joint records

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, count

I have the following tables in ACCESS

```
Table.KnowledgeArea | Table.CentralData | Table.AppointedHrs
--------------------+-------------------+-------------------
AreaKnowKey         | IdKey(key)        | ApointedHrsKey
AreaKnowDescr       | AreaKnowKey       | AppointedHrsDescr
                    | AppointedHrsKey   | 
                    | RFC               |
```

as you can see CentralData is related to KnowledgeArea and AppointedHrs

and I have the following SQL-query

```
SELECT KnowledgeArea.AreaKnowDescr, AppointedHrs.AppointedHrsDescr, CentralData.RFC
FROM AppointedHrs AS HRSNOMB, AppointedHrs 
INNER JOIN 
( KnowledgeArea INNER JOIN CentralData 
     ON KnowledgeArea.AreaKnowKey = CentralData.AreaKnowKey ) 
ON AppointedHrs.ApointedHrsKey = CentralData.ApointedHrsKey;
```

that produces the following browse-table

```
AreaKnowDescr        | AppointedHrsDescr | RFC
---------------------+-------------------+-----------
Ingeniería Aplicada. | Asignatura        | CUES730901
Ingeniería Aplicada. | Asignatura        | CUES730901
Ingeniería Aplicada. | Asignatura        | CUES730901
Ingeniería Aplicada. | Asignatura        | CUES730901
Ingeniería Aplicada. | Asignatura        | CUES730901
Ingeniería Aplicada. | Asignatura        | CUES730901
Ciencias Básicas.    | Asignatura        | CUGM700216
Ciencias Básicas.    | Asignatura        | CUGM700216
```

but I want something like

```
KnowledgeArea       | AppointedHrsDescr | Number of RFC
--------------------+-------------------+--------------
Ingeniería Aplicada | Asignatura        | 10
Ingeniería Aplicada | Tiempo Parcial    | 10
Ingeniería Aplicada | Tiempo Completo   | 10
Ciencias básicas    | Asignatura        | 5
Ciencias básicas    | Tiempo Parcial    | 5
Ciencias básicas    | Tiempo Completo   | 5
```

I know I have to use a count function. I have count record joining two tables but I have not been able to produce that I want.

Could anyone help me out, to get the propper SQL-sentence???

many thanks...

Comment: Why is this tagged with `mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

You have listed the AppointedHrs table twice here:

```
FROM AppointedHrs AS HRSNOMB, AppointedHrs
```

The comma is an out-dated syntax for a cross join, so you are combining every record in the table with every record in the table. That leads to those duplicates.

In order to count RFC per area and appointed hour, you must group by these two.

```
SELECT KnowledgeArea.AreaKnowDescr, AppointedHrs.AppointedHrsDescr, COUNT(*)
FROM AppointedHrs 
INNER JOIN 
( KnowledgeArea INNER JOIN CentralData 
     ON KnowledgeArea.AreaKnowKey = CentralData.AreaKnowKey ) 
ON AppointedHrs.ApointedHrsKey = CentralData.ApointedHrsKey
GROUP BY KnowledgeArea.AreaKnowDescr, AppointedHrs.AppointedHrsDescr
ORDER BY KnowledgeArea.AreaKnowDescr, AppointedHrs.AppointedHrsDescr;
```

And in case there can be duplicate descriptions (which I wouldn't recommend) you'd have to put the IDs in the `GROUP BY` clause, so as to get them separated in the results.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer. I just want to show alternative ways to write the same query.**

---

It is often a good idea to aggregate first and only then join. In standard SQL:

```
SELECT 
  ka.AreaKnowDescr,
  ah.AppointedHrsDescr,
  cd.RFCs
FROM 
(
  SELECT AreaKnowKey, ApointedHrsKey, COUNT(*) AS RFCs
  FROM CentralData
  GROUP BY AreaKnowKey, ApointedHrsKey
) cd
JOIN KnowledgeArea ka ON ka.AreaKnowKey = cd.AreaKnowKey
JOIN AppointedHrs ah ON ah.ApointedHrsKey = cd.ApointedHrsKey
ORDER BY ka.AreaKnowDescr, ah.AppointedHrsDescr;
```

In MS Access the same would look a bit clumsier and less readable for its need for parentheses on joins.

And here is the same without joins:

```
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT ka.AreaKnowDescr
    FROM KnowledgeArea ka
    WHERE ka.AreaKnowKey = cd.AreaKnowKey
  ) AS AreaKnowDescr,
  (
    SELECT ah.AppointedHrsDescr
    FROM AppointedHrs ah
    WHERE ah.ApointedHrsKey = cd.ApointedHrsKey
  ) AS AppointedHrsDescr,
  COUNT(*) AS RFCs
FROM CentralData cd
GROUP BY AreaKnowKey, ApointedHrsKey
ORDER BY AreaKnowDescr, AppointedHrsDescr;
```